# PrimeNG - TreeNodes [ ] populated but Empty TreeTable (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, tree, primeng, treetable

**Info: [PrimeNG TreeTable doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable)**

I'll try to make this as simple as possible.

**Goal**: tree table populated with *JSON* *itmes:*

**items.json**

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name": "item1",
      "description":"ServiceItem1",

   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"item2",
      "description":"ServiceItem2",

   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "name":"item3",
      "description":"ServiceItem3",

     }
]
```

**item.ts**

```
export class Item {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public description: string;

}
```

**TreeNode.ts**

```
export interface TreeNode {
    data?: any;
    children?: TreeNode[];
    leaf?: boolean;
    expanded?: boolean;
}
```

**item.service.ts**

```
export class BasketItemService {

getAllItems() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4203/assets/items.json');
  }
}
```

**item.component.ts**

```
  items: TreeNode[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getAllItems()
          .subscribe(
            res => {
              this.items = res.json();         
            },
            err => {
              console.log(err);
            }
          );
      }

    }
```

**item.component.html**

```
 <p-treeTable [value]="items" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode"></p-treeTableToggler> 
                {{rowData.id}}
            </td>
            <td>{{rowData.name}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

What i do get is a corected populated **items[]** list and no errors. The table is **empty** though. **There is no problem of imports or versions mismatch** because i implemented the example from their [site](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable) and it works perfectly.

The only **differences** are related to the JSON file, where, in their case, each **object is somehow labeled with *data* [or what node we're at](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable).(** Also, in the ngOnInit method, they do have

```
this.items = res.json().data;
```

Is this a must? Do my objects need to have attributes stricly named 'data'? Am i supposed to modify my TreeNode interface accordingly to my JSON or that is the pattern that must be fullfiled? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Json data is not proper. See the interfaces declared below, bind the josn data to TreeNodeModel. TreeTable expects data with children. Refer Primeng for more info.

```
export class Item {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
}

export class TreeNodeModel{
   expanded: boolean,
   data: Item,
   children: Array<TreeNodeModel>
}
```